# Angular Keyvalue pipe for nested object

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, async-pipe

I have http request that returns an observable object of objects. it contains many properities.
one of them is 'weight' object that contains two keyvalues, imperial and metric.

I am trying to loop over the keyvalues of the object but I am having issues rending the nested objects, it just shows

```
weight [object object]
```

my code

```
<div style=" margin : auto; border : 1px solid black; width : 70%; ">
<div style="display : flex;  justify-content : space-around; flex-wrap:wrap;">
  <div *ngFor="let breed of (breeds$ | async )" style="flex : 33%">
  <div *ngFor="let item of (breed | keyvalue : unsorted)">
    <div *ngIf="item.key === 'weight'">
      {{breed.weight.imperial}}
    </div>
    <b>{{item.key}}</b>{{item.value}}
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

my approach is just explicit

```
    <div *ngIf="item.key === 'weight'">
      {{breed.weight.imperial}}
    </div>
```

and doesn't work for other objects contained in the observable, and I think it is not really a good approach to the problem.

an example of data returned by the observable

```
    {
        "weight": {
            "imperial": "7  -  10",
            "metric": "3 - 5"
        },
        "id": "abys",
        "name": "Abyssinian",
        "image": {
            "id": "0XYvRd7oD",
            "width": 1204,
            "height": 1445,
            "url": "https://cdn2.thecatapi.com/images/0XYvRd7oD.jpg"
        }
    }
```

I tried replacing my explicit approach with

```
<div *ngIf="item.key === 'weight'">
<div *ngFor="let data of item.value">{{data.imperial}}</div>
</div>
```

but it shows this error

```
Type 'string | number | { imperial: string; metric: string; } | { id: string; width: number; height: number; url: string; }' is not assignable to type '(string & NgIterable<string>) | null | undefined'.ngtsc(2322)
```

Comment: You should use the "iterate variable" **item**, not "bread": `{{item.value.weight.imperial}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `weight` is an object, you need to apply `keyvalue` pipe to make it iterable.

```
<div *ngFor="let data of item.value | keyvalue">
  <span>{{ data.key }}</span>: <span>{{ data.value }}</span>
</div>
```

[Demo @ StackBltz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wqb2ut?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: it still produces this error 

`Argument of type 'string | number | { imperial: string; metric: string; } | { id: string; width: number; height: number; url: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Record<string, string | number | (() => string) | ((pos: number) => string) | ((index: number) => number) | ((...strings: string[]) => string) | ((searchString: string, position?: number | undefined) => number) | ... 43 more ... | (() => IterableIterator<...>)> | ReadonlyMap<...> | null | undefined'.ngtsc(2769)`

on item.value of this iteration

Comment: The latest error message is different from the previous error message. Can you create a demo in StackBlitz to reproduce the error mentioned? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for follow up; is this link working ? [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dm3vtw)

Comment: Look like you need `$any` method to escape the type checking. [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wgjvcu?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: is there a reason why is this the case ? or you could provide an explanation why. 
is it alright to allow $any in terms of Typescript best practises ?

Comment: Because when you pass `item.value` in `*ngFor`, TypeScript detects it is either of these types as mentioned in your attached error message. The type such as `string` and `number` is not iterable. `$any` is the way to prevent performing type checking. Best practise? Depends on your case. From my perspective, I will specify the property that I want to be displayed instead of using `*ngFor`. Using `*ngFor` is convenient if you want to display all properties without the worry of customization.

Answer (score 1):

Face the same problem, and I just solved it.

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-keyvalue-pipe-custom-compare-fn-wt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for a reference.

Write a compareFn for keyValue and wrap parament type, like `KeyValue<string, any>`

in typescript

```
  ...

  sortByValueAsc = (a: KeyValue<string, any>, b: KeyValue<string, any>) => {
    return 0
  };
```

and in HTML

```
<td *ngFor="let answer of surveyDetail.answer | keyvalue:sortByValueAsc">{{answer.value?.level}}</td>
```

Answer (score -1):

try something like this :

```
<div *ngFor="let breed of breeds">

  <div>{{ breed.weight.imperial }}</div>

  <div>{{ breed.weight.metric }}</div>

</div>
```

Comment: while it works for this case, I need something more 'dynamic' to just iterate over keys and values as there are more objects inside